# --source in cloudbuild.yaml

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I have my current Cloud Build working, I connect my github repo to trigger the Cloud Build when I push to the `main` branch which then creates my Cloud Function, but I am confused about the the `--source` flag.  I have read [the google cloud function docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--source).  They state that the
minimal source repository URL is: `https://source.developers.google.com/projects/${PROJECT}/repos/${REPO}`.  If I were to input this into my `cloudbuild.yaml` file, does this mean that I am mimicking the complete path of my github url?  I am currently just using `.` which I believe is just the entire root directory.

my cloudbuild.yaml file:

```
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    id: "deploypokedex"
    args:
      - functions
      - deploy
      - my_pokedex_function
      - --source=.
      - --entry-point=get_pokemon
      - --trigger-topic=pokedex
      - --timeout=540s
      - --runtime=python39
      - --region=us-central1
```

Comment: As stated in the documentation, the `--source` can be **any one of the three**: 1. Source code in Google Cloud Storage, 2. Reference to a source repo or 3. Local filesystem path. You are using Cloud Build to deploy the function so your GitHub repo is already connected hence `--source` should be `.` (root directory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are mimicking the complete path of the Github URL. `--source=.` means that you are calling the source code in your current working directory. You can check this link on [how to configure the Cloud Build deployment](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-functions#configuring_the_deployment).

Also based on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--source) you provided,

> If you do not specify the `--source` flag:
>
> - The current directory will be used for new function deployments.
> - If the function was previously deployed using a local filesystem path, then the function's source code will be updated using the current directory.
> - If the function was previously deployed using a Google Cloud Storage location or a source repository, then the function's source code will not be updated.

Let me know if you have questions or clarifications.